# SVN - Undo "Unversion"

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

We share some configuration files which are mostly identical from machine to machine other than a few custom sections. I was getting tired of always deselecting these files before every commit, so I read up on "Unversion and add to ignore list". My understanding was that these files would be ignored during commit operations, so I selected them and indicated to "Unversion ...".

Now when committing I'm seeing they are flagged for deletion. That is absolutely not what I'm wanting! These configuration files are needed by everyone including myself. They represent many hours of work and cannot be deleted. I'm really concerned that I'm going to mess up the repository.

Is there anything I can do to restore everything to before I did the "Unversion" stuff? This is after an update and some local modifications.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Unversioning merely removes from versioning. It does not physically delete the file from disk. The icon is misleading; if you commit, the dialog will even show that it was deleted. However, if you then refresh the view of the folder (with F5 in Explorer), you'll see the file is still there, but has no TSVN icon overlay. But yes, you can undo it with *Add (as replacement)* from the TSVN context menu (about three or four items above the one you used to unversion it).

Comment: @KenWhite - It says in the commit summary that the status of these files is "deleted". If I select these files, then commit, will these files still be in my local directory and unmodified (and intact) in the main repository?

Comment: They'll be in the local directory. They will *not* be in the repository, because you've removed them from versioning. If you *unversion* the files, you're telling SVN you don't want them to be in the repository because they're no longer under version control.

Comment: @KenWhite - thank you, so that's definitely not something I want to do!

Comment: @KenWhite Unfortunately, it seems that he Add operation isn't enough to undo the Unversion operation. I mean, if you deleted the files and then did the Unversion operation, then it seems unlikely that you'll be able to get these files in the repository.